# Использование подготовленного заявления Sqlite java

Tags: java, база-данных, sqlite

Всем доброго дня, впервые решил использовать Sqlite и вообще базу данных. Когда первый раз добавлял 100 записей, я чуть со стула не упал, ждал секунд 20. Потом прочитал про транзакции, всё, теперь занимает секунд 6. Но мне этого мало, я ещё вычитал про использование подготовленного заявления, но как это работает и как это использовать на java я нашёл только под android. Покажите примерчик с комментариями использования подготовленного заявления под ПК, пожалуйста.

Comment: [первая ссылка с гугла](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), [вторая ссылка с гугла](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/update/), не понятно как вы искали, но про андройд там ничего нет. Принцип всегда один в любом языке, БД и драйвере. пишите запрос с плейсхолдерами, готовите запрос, потом в цикле подставляете данные и выполняете подготовленный запрос. А вообще для вставки, можно использовать конструкцию с множественным `values`: `insert into ... values (1, 'xxx'), (2, 'yyy') ....`

Comment: Помимо скорости подготовленные запросы повышают безопасность, т.к. значения параметров передаются отдельно от тела запроса, исключая sql-инъекции.